# Insert json data in existing sqlite database?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I have sqlite file in asset folder and that is copied into sqlite database and at the time of app installation it display to user.
Now i want to insert new data from server json file.I have taken json data from server and done the parsing part successfully but it does not insert in existing database.
Code to parse json data and display it in list. There is no any error in code.But i can not insert it into the existing sqlite database.

```
    public void get_data(String data)
        {

            try {
                JSONArray data_array=new JSONArray(data);

                for (int i = 0 ; i < data_array.length() ; i++)
                {
                    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(data_array.get(i).toString());

                    Message add=new Message();


                    add.category = obj.getString("category");
                    add.status = obj.getString("status");
                    add.imagelink=obj.getString("imglink");
                    objlist.add(add);
                    db1.addSMS(add);
                }

                new ListAdapter(CatagoryActivity.this, objlist).notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        public ArrayList<Message> getMessages() {
            ArrayList<Message> objlist_msg = new ArrayList<Message>();
            Message obj;
            adp.open();
            Cursor c = adp.Catagorylist();
            c.moveToFirst();
            /*
             * Toast.makeText(CatagoryActivity.this, "" + c.getCount(),
             * Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show();
             */

            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                obj = new Message();

                String msg = c
                        .getString(c.getColumnIndex(MessagesAdapter.CATEGORY));
                String imagelink = c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex(MessagesAdapter.Imagelink));

                obj.setImagelink(imagelink);
                Cursor c1 = adp.getcount(msg);
                c1.moveToFirst();
                int count = c1.getCount();
                obj.setCategory(msg);
                obj.setCount(String.valueOf(count));
                objlist_msg.add(obj);

                c.moveToNext();
            }

            adp.close();
            return objlist_msg;
        }

        public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context context;
            private ArrayList<Message> objlist;

            public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> objlist) {
                this.context = context;
                this.objlist = objlist;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                ViewHolder holder=null;
                if(convertView==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                holder=new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.catagory_list_raw, null);
                holder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                }else{
                    holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
                }
                holder.txt.setText(objlist.get(position).getCategory().toString());

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return objlist.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return objlist.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }


        }

        class ViewHolder{
            TextView txt,count;
        }


     //This function in Database.java file



    public void addSMS(Message sms) {
            SQLiteDatabase db123 = this.getWritableDatabase();
            try{
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MessagesAdapter.CATEGORY, sms.getCategory());
                values.put(MessagesAdapter.Status, sms.getStatus());
                values.put(MessagesAdapter.Imagelink,sms.getImagelink());
                db123.insert(MessagesAdapter.TBL_CATEGORY, null, values);
                //Log.e("TAG","JSON DATA INSERTED");
                db123.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("problem",e+"");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please show what have you tried?

Comment: where is option to add my source code here?sorry to ask but i am new on stack overflow

Comment: add code in your question....

Comment: Just add code and select your code portion and type `ctrl+k` or check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51145/256622)

Comment: when you are asked to add your code, the expectation isn't all of your code. Add only the relevent bits please. If there are any exceptions or errors please update the question with them too

Comment: Do you have any error message or backtrace? Also, that is too much code to read. Where does the problem occur? Show the code around there primarily.

Comment: There is no any error in code.But i can not insert it into the existing sqlite database.[In existing database there is only data which is in asset file]

Comment: Did you tried to print database row size after inserting a data?

Comment: No but i tried it on logcat.. after displaying logcat massege i got the thing it not inserted.